# Spring openapi ui webflux not working on Native mode

Tags: java, spring, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

I am currently in the process of playing around with Graal native for SpringBoot by enabling it on a service that I already have in the wild. For the most part, everything works fine. I am using all the latest versions and I experience no problems so far.

I have successfully packaged the executable created by running `./gradlew nativeBuild` into a Docker image using a very simple `Dockerfile`.

While this work fine, when I try to access the OpenAPI UI (under /webjars/swagger-ui/index.html) I get a 404. Now the weird thing is that this occurs some times and not always, as it seems that in some cases I am able to access the OpenAPI UI with no issues. However on other cases I get the 404 mentioned above. I am really puzzled about this since the behavior is not consistent.

For reference I am using all the latest versions of the various libraries/dependencies. Any ideas as to what might be happening?

Comment: Hi @akourt! Did you manage to solve the problem with native?

Comment: @user6354846 yes I did. Apparently the configuration class of SpringUI gets initialized on compilation with whatever values are at that point in the `application.yaml` or any other property provider. In my case I wanted to switch SwaggerUI on production but due to this feature injecting configuration during runtime is not possible. I hope at some point this is fixed but the trick is to simply enable everything by default.